# How to align columns of parameters of code?

Tags: vim

Let's say that I have a few dozens of lines of code that look like this:

```
callbacks.registerFunction("position", bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::position, movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("setPosition", bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::setPosition, movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("translate", bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::translate, movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("positionDelta", bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::positionDelta, movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("measuredVelocity", bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::measuredVelocity, movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("velocity", bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::velocity, movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("setVelocity", bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::setVelocity, movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("setXVelocity", bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::setXVelocity, movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("setYVelocity", bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::setYVelocity, movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("applyForce", bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::applyForce, movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("control", bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::control, movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("xControl", bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::xControl, movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("yControl", bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::yControl, movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("inLiquid", bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::inLiquid, movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("onGround", bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::onGround, movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("collisionBounds", bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::collisionBounds, movementController, _1));
```

I want them to look like:

```
callbacks.registerFunction("position",         bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::position,         movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("setPosition",      bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::setPosition,      movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("translate",        bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::translate,        movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("positionDelta",    bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::positionDelta,    movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("measuredVelocity", bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::measuredVelocity, movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("velocity",         bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::velocity,         movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("setVelocity",      bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::setVelocity,      movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("setXVelocity",     bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::setXVelocity,     movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("setYVelocity",     bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::setYVelocity,     movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("applyForce",       bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::applyForce,       movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("control",          bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::control,          movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("xControl",         bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::xControl,         movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("yControl",         bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::yControl,         movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("inLiquid",         bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::inLiquid,         movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("onGround",         bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::onGround,         movementController, _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("collisionBounds",  bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::collisionBounds,  movementController, _1));
```

The blocks are offset by newlines so you can use { and } to navigate across them.

And I'd like to make a macro or function or something to do this.  But it feels like I'm missing some important tools in my vim toolbox because I have no idea how to begin approaching this problem.

For instance, I don't know how to insert a variable number of spaces depending on the column of a particular mark, which I assume the solution involves.

I'm aware it's easy enough to do with visual block selection manually.  But I have a lot of code to format, and I was hoping to avoid having to resort to a manual solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at [plugin Tabular](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3464).

With the first lines of your text, you can use this command:

```
:%Tabularize /,
```

to get following output:

```
callbacks.registerFunction("position"         , bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::position         , movementController , _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("setPosition"      , bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::setPosition      , movementController , _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("translate"        , bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::translate        , movementController , _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("positionDelta"    , bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::positionDelta    , movementController , _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("measuredVelocity" , bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::measuredVelocity , movementController , _1));
```

I don't know if it's possible to have the comma before spaces, though. Maybe you can find something by looking at this plugin in detail (otherwise, a simple substitution should do the trick).

**Edit:** The `%` in command seems to be useless. Also with a space as a delimiter, you get an output closer to what you are looking for:

```
:Tabularize / /
```

Output:

```
callbacks.registerFunction("position",           bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::position,           movementController,   _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("setPosition",        bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::setPosition,        movementController,   _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("translate",          bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::translate,          movementController,   _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("positionDelta",      bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::positionDelta,      movementController,   _1));
callbacks.registerFunction("measuredVelocity",   bind(MovementControllerCallbacks::measuredVelocity,   movementController,   _1));
```

Comment: To put the commas before the spaces: `:Tab /,\zs/`

Comment: @JimDavis: works well indeed, even better than my 2nd solution. I had never used `\zs` before, so I went through `vim` help and saw that it matches at any position, and sets the start of the match there (in case someone else wonders).

Comment: `\zs` is very handy and even mentioned in the Tabular documentation. This is the command I cam up with to `:Tabularize/,\zs/l1l0l0` which does the spacing correctly after the comma